# Nautilus times out too soon

Tags: nautilus, shared-folders, nas, timeout

I have a NAS with all my music on it. It's a large collection, so listing up all folders with artists takes some time. However, Nautilus seems to give a time out when it's not able to fetch the list within a couple of seconds. I'm pretty sure the problem is at the client side, since OSX is able to show the list.

Is there a way to increase the time before such error is thrown?

Comment: How are you connecting to the NAS? sshfs, samba... ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. It's using AFP.

Comment: AFP isn't a really ironed out protocol yet, is there anything tying you to it? Maybe you should try SSHFS.